# NaN produced in a matrix decomposition

Tags: r

I've found a written function of Cholesky decomposition. Chol() runs smoothly on all set matrixes, unfortunately the full code I found on Git doesn't. it produces:

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(m[i, i] - p.sum) : NaNs produced
```

Another thing it works on an example symetrical matrix like:

```
(A <- matrix(c(5, 1, 2, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 7), 3))
```

Of course I can use chol() function but i'm trying to discover the logic laying behind this code:

```
choleskymatrix <- function(m) {
count.rows <- nrow(m)
count.cols <- ncol(m)

L = diag(0, count.rows)
for(i in 1:count.rows) {
    for(k in 1:i) {
        p.sum <- 0
        for(j in 1:k)
            p.sum <- p.sum + L[j, i] * L[j, k]
        if(i == k)
            L[k, i] <- sqrt(m[i, i] - p.sum)
        else
            L[k, i] <- (m[k, i] - p.sum) / L[k, k]
    }
}
return(L)
}
```

Can someone tell me, where these error comes from?

Comment: Since it is a square root function, I assume that the arguement is negative. I don't know the logic for Cholesky, but maybe try  `sqrt(abs(m[i, i] - p.sum))`

Comment: And that's the solution, thank you!